# test case for hidden field is not working with cucumber

Tags: cucumber, capybara

```
fill_in "user_role", :with => @visitor[:role]
```

This is checking simple input field but input field with hidden it is not working for that is there any other method for hidden field.

Comment: what does this have to do with Cucumber?

Comment: Just need to check the hidden field value

Comment: Cucumber doesn't fill that field in. A ruby library helps to fill that field in, such as watir-webdriver or capybara. You should tag with that to get better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hidden_field = find :xpath, "//input[@id='id_of_hidden_field']"
hidden_field.set "hello world"
```

Comment: this is the id of Hidden field , user_role,